# Show exactly n Lines on a GridView

Tags: android, gridview, visible

How can i show exactly 2 lines in a GridView and scroll to show the other items? Thanks in advance.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to do this, other than to dynamically size your `GridView` to be exactly two rows tall.

Answer (score 1):

You can give it a fixed height

```
<GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/previous"
        android:columnWidth="150dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dip"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="30dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

if here 2 lines are for 2 Columns then see this

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#setNumColumns(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#setNumColumns%28int%29)

or in XML inside grid tag

android:numColumns="2"

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what i want is 2 row and not too columns.

Comment: ohh I thought two vertical line :)

Comment: @Vervatovskis please see this link would be help ful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11045743/android-add-n-number-of-views-in-scroll-view/11049433#11049433