# android - add n number of views in scroll view

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview, android-inflate

i am designing an app for android tablets. I have created a layout file which contains the application bar, next is some buttons. In the middle of the screen i want to have a horizontal scroll view inside which i need to show some images.

The number of images inside the scroll view depends upon the return data from the url. For this i am maintaining an array list. According to the size of the array i need to create the image views withing the scroll view.

`I have placed all other buttons, textviews in the layout file and i need to make the above said view alone through coding`, how to do this.

If the array size is 19, then the list of images within scroll view to be shown in the following order only

```
1  4  7  10  13  16  19
2  5  8  11  14  17    
3  6  9  12  15  18
```

In iPad iBook apps library page, the books will be listed out in this way.

how to do this....

Comment: Are there three horizontal scrollviews? Or a Listview with each row being a horizontal scrollview

Comment: @Sana - only one horizontal scroll view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Dheeresh Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/804447/dheeresh-singh)

Following is my main.xml file

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

i have my `Horizontal scroll view` in my `main.xml` file

```
public class LayoutActivity extends Activity 
//implements OnClickListener
{
    ViewGroup layout;
    LinearLayout lr;

    int x;
    int total = 4;
    int count = 0;
    LinearLayout lay;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        count = 0;
        layout = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.linear_1);
        x = (total/3)+(total%3 > 0?1:0);;
        for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        {
            lr = new LinearLayout(this);
            lr.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            layout.addView(lr);
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++ )
            {
                count++;
                final View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.inflateview, null);
                lay = (LinearLayout)child.findViewById(R.id.threeByThree_tableRow1_1_Layout1);
                lay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
                {   
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) 
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "selected  id  is "+child.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                lr.addView(child);
                child.setId(count);
                if(i == total)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }      
    }
}
```

in the above code i have lr is the LinearLayout to display it in vertical order and View child is the data which i need to show in both vertical and horizontal order.

Thanks a lot [Dheeresh Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/804447/dheeresh-singh)

Comment: a small mistake .... child.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  should be inside the inner loop :)

Comment: I have one query where you initalized layout variable of "layout.addView(lr);"

Comment: no use.. now where ever i click the toast msg seems to be the fianl number

Comment: no need Xml jasu asking where is findViewById for  layout variable of "layout.addView(lr);"

Comment: can you implement the listener as I said in my answer implement View.OnClickListener in your activty and pass this in  child.setOnClickListener() and setTag and getTag from image view

Comment: there is error in the following line if(obj instanceof Integer)
     {
      position  = (Integer(obj )).intValue();
     } saying that  Create method 'Integer(Object)'

Comment: i have added the method   private Object Integer(Object obj) 
 {
  return null;
 } and now it shows error in ".intValue();" saying Add cast to Integer(obj)

Comment: it's Integer  class there no need to make ............. where it requires ? must typo error

Comment: Hai i copy this code in my proj but    final View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.inflateview, null);
              lay = (LinearLayout)child.findViewById(R.id.threeByThree_tableRow1_1_Layout1); this line is underlined by redline, so please send the xml inflateview layout and contents

Answer (score 1):

not sure but can try approach like this

```
1- Create/inflate a horizontal scrollview ..
2- make for loop running i= 0 to x 
        where x= (totalCount/3)+(totalCount%3>0?1:0)
3- Create a  Linear layout with orientation vertical  
4- create one more loop form j=0 to 3 or (i+1)*3+j< totalCount
5- add your element layout in  Linear layout 
6 after the inner loop closed add Linear layout in horizontal scroll-view
```

- loop termination condition like the value of x may not be exact please check them

For making item clickable

```
1- take any view from  element layout like in you case image-view is good option  
 2- creates a class in you activity or better to extend you activity with clickListner.
 3- while creating the imageView for each element set this listener to all
 4- Set the data object or index  with element with image-view in tad using SetTag
 5- in Onclick function you will get image-view as argument and use getTag to get that data of attached with clicked element
```

Comment: i have implemented as you have said. I have got the same view multiple times as i need. But when is click on those i am not getting the toast msg. I have added the complete solution below

Comment: The toast msg appears only for the last view with the correct tag number and not for the others...